# What is the difference between "have been doing to" and "have been doing with"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Let's say someone has been looking after my dog for the day and at the end of the day the dog is really tired. I want to know why. What is the right way to ask:

"what have you been doing to my dog"?

or

"what have you been doing with my dog?"

If I ask "what have you been doing to my dog?", it sounds to me like I suspect something bad has been done to my dog. It has a slightly accusatory or suspicious feel to it. Is it also possible to use this in a jokingly manner?

Would "what have you been doing with my dog?" be a more neutral question, as in "what activities have you been undertaking?" without expressing any suspicion at all?

Comment: Yes, you could ask "What have you been doing to my dog?" in a humorous manner. You could also express the question as "What have the two of you been doing/been up to?"

Comment: @Kate Bunting Then what does "what have you been doing with my dog" mean, in your opinion? Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: _Doing with_ can mean either _doing to_ or _doing in company with_, so, as you say, it is a more neutral question.

Comment: So my description of both expressions is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. _Doing to_ could sound accusatory, but could be said jokingly.